# Moving partition on Gparted

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I moved the partition called boot area to the end of the disk, so I could expand another partition using GParted in Rescue Linux (Linux that runs on a USB flash drive) and it gave me this error.

```
ntfsresize -i -f -v '/dev/sda5' 00:00:00 (ERROR)
     
ntfsresize v2021.8.22 (libntfs-3g)
Failed to read last sector (999991): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
ERROR(22): Opening '/dev/sda5' as NTFS failed: Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't have a valid NTFS.
Maybe you selected the wrong partition? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/hda, not /dev/hda1)? This error might also occur
if the disk was incorrectly repartitioned (see the ntfsresize FAQ).
```

Comment: How is this related with Ubuntu?